# ListView with custom positioned childern

Tags: android

I need implement custom View with adapter, similar to ListView, but i need position of elements not in row(look on image).

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mkLV.png)

I can do this with custom layout, but i need recucling view, because in my list will be a lot of items (100 - 200);

So there is question: how can i extend ListView to position children by myself?
(I allready try, but i cant use RecuclerBin, because it is private class of AbsListVew).
I will appreciate any help...

Comment: Really late answer, but you can just use grid view

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, I would use to list for that.